# The set $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^{2n} ; x \neq y\}$ is connected if $n \geq 2$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

When n = 1 it is easy to see that is not connected, it just take the split open $ S=U_1 \cup U_2$ such that $U_1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x > y\}$ is $U_2 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x < y\}$ not trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma 1.** If $x,y,u,v\in\mathbb R^n$ are such that  $x-y,u-v$ are linearly independent, then the straight line joining $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ is a subset of $S$.

*Proof:* The general point on the line is of the form $t(x,y)+(1-t)(u,v)$. If such a point is $\notin S$, then $tx+(1-t)u=ty+(1-t)v$, i.e. $t(x-y)+(1-t)(u-v)=0$. By linear independence, $t=1-t=0$, contradiction. $_\square$

**Lemma 2.** If $V$ is a vector space,  $u,v,w\in V$ and $u,v$ are linearly independent, and $u,w$ are linearly dependent, and $v,w$ are linearly dependent, then $w=0$.

*Proof:* Assume $au+bw=cv+dw=0$ with $(a,b)\ne 0$ and $(c,d)\ne 0$. If $a=0$ or $c=0$ we are done. From $0=d(au+bw)-b(cv+dw)=adu-bcv$, we conclude $ad=bc=0$ and then $d=b=0$. But then $au=cv$. $_\square$

**Proposition.** If $u,v\in\mathbb R^n$ are linearly independent and $(x,y)\in S$, then one of the straight lines connecting $(x,y)$ with $(0,u)$ or with $(0,v)$ is s subset of $S$.

*Proof:* Let $w=x-y$ in lemma 2. As $(x,y)\in S$, w have $w\ne 0$, hence $u,w$ or $v,w$ are linearly independent. Then the claim follows form lemma 1. $_\square$

**Corollary.** If $n\ge 2$ then $S$ is path connected.

*Proof:* We can find two linearly independent vectors $u,v$ in $\mathbb R^n$.
By lemma 1, the straight line from $(0,u)$ to $(0,v)$ is in $S$ and any point $(x,y)\in S$ is path connected to one of these two points by the proposition. $_\square$

Comment: Okay, good. Well laborious but it works very well. S is path connected then S is connected.

Answer (score 3):

Up to a rotation of $\mathbb R ^{2n}$ you ask for which $n$ the space $\mathbb R^{2n} - \mathbb R^{n}$ is path connected, where $\mathbb R^{n}$ sits in the first $n$ coordinates. But contracting the first $n$ coordinates is a homotopy equivalence ending in $\mathbb R^{n} - 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $n=2$. Imagine you have $2$ pairs of points in a plane (the coordinates of $2$ points in $\mathbb R^{2\cdot2}$). Can you transform one pair into the other without collapsing it to a point anywhere along the way?

---

**Answer:** Consider two pairs of point $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$.

If we find a continuous transformation $\varphi(t):[0,1]\to\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n$, $\varphi(t)=(\varphi_1(t),\varphi_2(t))$ such that $\varphi(0)=(x_1,y_1)$, $\varphi(1)=(x_2,y_2)$ and $\varphi_1(t)\ne\varphi_2(t)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, then $\varphi$ determines an arc in $S=R^{2n}\setminus\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb R^n\}$ connecting the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.

It's easy to see there are many ways to do it. E.g. in $n=2$ we can always connect the points like this and obviously $\varphi_1(t)\ne\varphi_2(t)$, because the arcs don't even intersect.

[image]

In a formal proof, you would use polygonal lines and you should do that yourself.

Comment: I wanted to clarify a function and thought that:$\Phi(t)=((1-t)x_1+tx_2$,$(1-t)y_1 +ty_2)=(\Phi_1(t)$,$\Phi_2(t))$ but I can not show that $ \Phi_1(t) \ne \Phi_2(t)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @user79048 Because if e.g. if $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$ lie on the same line, this work work. You'll probably need to take care of some cases.

Comment: This function is not valid for $x_1=y_1$ is $x_2=y_2$, because these functions would be the same for all $t \in [0,1]$.